# Why will Powershell write to the console, but not to a file?

Tags: powershell-2.0, output

I have a PowerShell script that sets flags based on various conditions of the file. I'll abbreviate for brevity.

```
$path = "c:\path"
$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $path -filter *.htm*

ForEach ($doc in $srcfiles) {

$s = $doc.Fullname

Write-Host "Processing :" $doc.FullName

if (stuff) {flag 1 = 1} else {flag 1 = 0}
if (stuff) {flag 1 = 1} else {flag 1 = 0}
if (stuff) {flag 1 = 1} else {flag 1 = 0}

$t = "$s;$flag1;$flag2;$flag2"

Write-Host "Output: " $t
```

This all works great. My file processes, the flags are set properly, and a neat semicolon delimited line is generated as $t. However, if I slap these two lines at the end of the function,

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "flags.txt"
$stream.WriteLine $t
```

I get this error.

```
Unexpected token 't' in expression or statement.
At C:\CGC003a.ps1:53 char:25
+     $stream.WriteLine $t <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (t:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

If I'm reading this write, it appears that `write-host` flushed my variable `$t` before it got to the `WriteLine`. Before I try `out-file`, though, I want to understand what's happening to `$t` after Write-Host that prevents `Write Line` from seeing it as valid. Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
$stream.WriteLine($t)
```

writeline is a method of `streamwriter` .net object. To pass in value you need to enclose it in `( )`

-if you need to append to a streamwriter you need to create it like this:

```
$a = new-object 'System.IO.StreamWriter' -ArgumentList "c:\path\to\flags.txt",$true
```

Where the boolean arguments can be true to append data to the file orfalse to overwrite the file.

I suggest to pass full path for:

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "c:\path\to\flags.txt"
```

otherwise you create the file in .net current folder ( probably c:\windows\system32 if run as administrator your current powershell console, to know it type `[System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()`)

Comment: Awesome! That at least gets me a different error...my first record writes to the file, then I get runtime errors that it's in use by another process...which makes sense. Is there a -force switch for the streamwriter method that'll override that file lock? It doesn't like `-append`.

Comment: Um... streamwriter object needs to be .closed() and eventually .disposed() after used to unlock file. If you had overwrite the $stream variable you need to close powershell and re-open to unlock file. And not oper your stramwriter in the loop, just before the loop, and close it at the and of your script

Comment: Yes, I understand about `.closing` the file...but as it iterates through the `foreach ($doc)`, would I need to close it at the end of each iteration? I would think I'd only need to `close` the file at the END of all my iterations...what am I missing?

Comment: Have your read my previous comment? You have to close the streamwriter out of the loop when you not need write in more data. follow?

Comment: Why are you using `StreamWriter` instead of `Out-File` anyways?

Comment: @C.B. Yes, I did read the other comments; I was just asking for clarification.

Comment: @StanleyDeBoer  I was getting other errors with `out-file`. It iterated through all the records without displaying errors until the FINAL record, which returns `wildcard path does not resolve to a file` and I'm left with an empty file. Just tryin' something else.

Comment: @StanleyDeBoer `StreamWriter` is much faster and has less overhead than `Out-File`. I'm working a project with performance demands, I have run tests with both implementations writing 10k records 10k times and measured each execution. On average, `StreamWriter` was a couple miliseconds short of being 3 times faster than `Out-File`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
$t > c:\path\to\flags.txt
```

Comment: Whilst this definitely works, it's much less efficient (and thus slower) than using a `StreamWriter` - especially over a network/remote connection. --- See: http://blogs.technet.com/b/gbordier/archive/2009/05/05/powershell-and-writing-files-how-fast-can-you-write-to-a-file.aspx